# Java XStream starting level

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have an XML document like

```
<ListOfCats>
    <Cat>
        <Name>Mittens</Name>
    </Cat>
<ListOfCats>
```

that I'm deserializing using XStream like

```
ListOfCats mewlings = (ListOfCats)xstream.fromXML(xml);
```

but then I have to access them like

```
mewlings.getCat().get(1).getName()
```

to get the names.

I'd much rather prefer to just have an ArrayList of Cats instead of a ListOfCats of Cats so I could access them like

```
mewlingArray[1].getName();
```

Is it possible to set the starting level of XStream so I can skip the `<ListOfCats>`?

EDIT: Not really an answer to my question but I decided to just iterate through the ListOfCats and add each Cat to an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an accessor method to the ListOfCats so you can call `getCat(1)`.